# AWS operation prevents other operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the management console I am currently changing the storage class for some folders in one bucket (Standard-IA) and while that operation is happening I am unable to cut and paste in another bucket.

When I go to select the folders in the other bucket and select the drop down or actions the folders are unselected.

Is this by design or is something else causing this in my management console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I just had to open another tab and try there.

Comment: There is (afaik) no such thing in S3 as changing the storage class for a folder, so the console must be emulating that action in the background by changing the class of the individual objects.  Strange but possible that the option is disabled due to that background action.